# Outputting a report with a header and a table in java

Tags: java, methods, header, report

I'm supposed to be outputting a report in a window. I created a method for the table and header, but when I run the program they're outputting to separate windows. I know I need to create another method to display the report, but I can't figure out what the right formals are.

Here's what I have and what it's supposed to look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY1TP.png)

```
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main
{

    static String name, address, city, state;
    static int zip, month, date, year, code;
    static double amount = 0, rate = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputFile loanInfo;
        loanInfo = new InputFile("fcrc loan data.txt");

        JFrame jf;
        JTextArea jta;
        JScrollPane jsp;

        jf = new JFrame();
        jta = new JTextArea();
        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);

        jf.setSize(1200, 350);
        jf.setLocation(400, 250);

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.add(jsp);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        while (!loanInfo.eof()) 
        {
            name = loanInfo.readString();
            address = loanInfo.readString();
            city = loanInfo.readString();
            state = loanInfo.readWord();
            zip = loanInfo.readInt();
            month = loanInfo.readInt();
            date = loanInfo.readInt();
            year = loanInfo.readInt();
            amount = loanInfo.readDouble();
            rate = loanInfo.readDouble();
            code = loanInfo.readInt();

            displayReport();

/*I know this is probably where the issue is. I just don't know what the appropriate formals are to finish the method*/


        }

    }
    
    public static void displayReport()
    {
        displayHeading(name, address, city, state, zip, month, date, year, amount, code, rate);
        displayTable(amount);
        
    }

    public static void displayTable(double amount)
    {
        int paymentNumber;

        double payment = 0, interest, principal, balance;

        JFrame jf;
        JTextArea jta;
        JScrollPane jsp;

        jf = new JFrame();
        jta = new JTextArea();
        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);

        jf.setSize(1200, 350);
        jf.setLocation(400, 250);

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.add(jsp);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        DecimalFormat numFormat;
        numFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        NumberFormat currencyFormat;
        currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        balance = amount;
        paymentNumber = 0;
        double totalPayment = 0;
        double totalIntPaid = 0;
        while (balance > 0) 
        {

            ++paymentNumber;
            String dueDate = calcDueDate(month, date, year, paymentNumber - 1);
            interest = calcInterest(balance, rate);
            if (balance <= payment) 
            {
                payment = balance;
                principal = balance;
                balance = 0;
            } else 
            {
                payment = calcPayment(code, amount);
                principal = calcPrincipal(payment, interest);
                balance = calcBalance(balance, principal);
            }
            totalPayment = totalPayment + payment;
            totalIntPaid = totalIntPaid + interest;
            jta.append(paymentNumber + "\t\t" + dueDate + "\t\t$" + numFormat.format(payment) + "\t\t" + currencyFormat.format(interest) + "\t\t" + currencyFormat.format(principal) + "\t\t" + currencyFormat.format(balance) + "\n");

        }
        
        jta.append("\n");
        jta.append(" " + "\t\t" + " " + "\t\t" + "Totals: " + currencyFormat.format(totalPayment) + "\t" + currencyFormat.format(totalIntPaid) + "\n");
        jta.append("\n\n");

    }

    public static void displayHeading(String name, String address1, String city, String state, int zip, int month, int day, int year, double amount, int code, double rate)
    {
        DecimalFormat numFormat;
        numFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        NumberFormat currencyFormat;
        currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        JFrame jf;
        JTextArea jta;
        JScrollPane jsp;

        jf = new JFrame();
        jta = new JTextArea();
        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);

        jf.setSize(1200, 350);
        jf.setLocation(400, 250);

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.add(jsp);
        jf.setVisible(true);

        jta.append("First Community Redevelopment Corporation\n");
        jta.append("101 1st Street\n");
        jta.append("Bloomington, TN 41663\n");
        jta.append("\n");
        jta.append("\t\t\t\t" + name + "\n");
        jta.append("\t\t\t\t" + address1 + "\n");
        jta.append("\t\t\t\t" + city + ", " + state + ", " + zip + "\n");
        jta.append("\n");
        jta.append("LOAN AMOUNT:\t\t" + currencyFormat.format(amount) + "\n");
        jta.append("INTEREST RATE:\t\t" + numFormat.format(rate) + "%\n");
        jta.append("\n");
        jta.append("Payment #\tDue Date\t\tPayment\t\tInterest\tPrincipal\tBalance\n");
        jta.append("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
   

    public static double calcPayment(int code, double amount)
    {
        double payment;
        payment = 0;

        switch (code) 
        {
            case 0:
                payment = 50.00;
                break;
            case 1:
                payment = 55.00;
                break;
            case 2:
                payment = 75.00;
                break;
            case 3:
                payment = 100.00;
                break;
            case 4:
                payment = .05 * amount;
                break;
            case 5:
                payment = .06 * amount;
                break;
            case 6:
                payment = .05 * amount;
                break;
            case 7:
                payment = .04 * amount;
                break;
            case 8:
                payment = .03 * amount;
                break;
            case 9:
                payment = .02 * amount;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Bad payment code");
        }
        return payment;
    }

    public static double calcInterest(double balance, double rate)
    {
        double interest;
        interest = rate / 12 * balance;
        return interest;
    }

    public static double calcPrincipal(double payment, double interest)
    {
        double principal;

        principal = payment - interest;
        return principal;
    }

    public static double calcBalance(double balance, double principal)
    {
        balance -= principal;
        return balance;
    }

    public static String calcDueDate(int month, int day, int year, int payNum)
    {
        String monthStr = "";
        month = month + payNum - 1;
        year = year + (month / 12);
        month = month % 12;
        if (month == 0) 
        {
            year--;
        }
        switch (month) 
        {
            case 1:
                monthStr = "Jan.";
                break;
            case 2:
                monthStr = "Feb.";
                break;
            case 3:
                monthStr = "Mar.";
                break;
            case 4:
                monthStr = "Apr.";
                break;
            case 5:
                monthStr = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                monthStr = "Jun.";
                break;
            case 7:
                monthStr = "Jul.";
                break;
            case 8:
                monthStr = "Aug.";
                break;
            case 9:
                monthStr = "Sept.";
                break;
            case 10:
                monthStr = "Oct.";
                break;
            case 11:
                monthStr = "Nov.";
                break;
            case 0:
                monthStr = "Dec.";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid month: " + month);

        }
        return monthStr + " " + day + ", " + year;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `InputFile` and where is it? A few lines of fictitious file data to wouldn't hurt either. Where you think you're having the problem will not open another window however, the `displayTable()` method will because you are telling it to. You only need to create the window once.

Answer (score 0):

Below is your application which I reworked a little bit. There were some equations and code changes made for things to work properly. Read the comments in code:

Because you neglected to answer my question within the comments section of you post I had to create an **InputFile** class and assume the layout of file data which is shown directly below:

**Data File Demo (`"fcrc loan data.txt"`):**

```
Bill Olsen
914 8th Street
Salt Lake City
UT
64112
;USA
;801-364-0809
;billolsen@gmail.com
3
1
2004
1250.00
5.25
2
```

Any file lines starting with `;` are considered commented and application properties requiring the data from those lines will be provided with a Null String ("").

**The application startup (entry) class:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class
                    .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        
        // Started this way to avoid the need for everything to be static.
        new Main().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        /* Instantiate an instance of the LoanPaymentsReport class:
           There a few contructors for this class. Here are the ways
           you can instantiate this class and provide the minimal
           required data to generate a payment table which is: 
        
            - The Loan Amount (floating point value), 
            - The Interest Rate (floatingpoint value), 
            - The Payment Code (integer value),
            - The Start Month (integer value)           - Optional,
            - The Start Day (integer value)             - Optional,
            - The Start Year (four digit integer value) - Optional.
           
           If the date components are not supplied then the current 
           Month of Year value, 1st day of month value, and current 4
           digit Year value is used.              */
        
        /* With this Constructor, class Setter methods will need to 
           be used to supply the minimal required and desired data. */
       // LoanPaymentsReport report = new LoanPaymentsReport();
        
        /* With this Constructor, all minimal required data is supplied
           except the date components (Month, Day, and Year). They are 
           optional with this constructor and if not supplied then the 
           current Month of Year value, 1st day of month value, and 
           current 4 digit Year value is used. If you just want to change 
           the Starting Month then you can supply that month number as 
           the last constructor argument. If you want to just supply the
           month and year then, you must also supply the start Day. The
           date components are in the format: m, d, yyyy.     */
        //LoanPaymentsReport report = 
                //                                            These 3 are Optional
                //                       Loan    Int.   Pmt.  Start   Start   Start
                //                      Amount   Rate   Code  Month    Day    Year
        //      new LoanPaymentsReport(1250.00d, 3.25d,  2,     3,      1,    2004);
        
        /* With this Constructor, the supplied data file fulfills the
           minimal required data plus more like Customer information.
           If there is customer data (like country, phone number, EMail,
           etc) you do not want displayed then leave a blank line exactly
           where that specific data resides within the file OR, add a 
           semicolon (;) at the start of the data line to omit. Ultimately,
           you could potentially have several blank lines or lines starting
           with semicolons within the data file where you want to omit data 
           from display. Comapny information will still need to be provided 
           via the LoanPaymentsReport Setter methods as shown below.      */  
        LoanPaymentsReport report = new LoanPaymentsReport("fcrc loan data.txt");
        
        /* Comment any Constructors you don't want to use and uncomment the
           the Constructor you do want to use and play with this software. 
           Also, if you like, go into the LoanPaymentsReport class and create 
           (overload) whatever Constuctors you think might be benificial.*/
            
        /* You don't have to set any of the following properties since
           they are ALL Null String ("") by default. But if you want to
           see a Company Name and address etc, then you would want to ad
           demonstrated here to show what can be provided for company Info.
           Again, always keep in mind, if you don't fill the below company
           related properties then those properties will not be displayed 
           winthin the Text Area. Only the properties that contain data will 
           be visible within the report.                     */
        report.setCompanyName("First Community Redevelopment Corporation");
        report.setCompanyAddress("101 1st Street");
        report.setCompanyCity("Bloomington");
        report.setCompanyState("TN");
        report.setCompanyZip("41663"); 
        report.setCompanyCountry("");  
        report.setCompanyPhone("");    
        report.setCompanyEMail("");
       
        /* This below does exactly the same thing as above however, 
           something must be provided for ALL company properties!  */
        String[] companyInfo = {"First Community Redevelopment Corporation", "101 1st Street",
                                "Bloomington", "TN", "41663", "", "", ""};
        report.setCompanyInfo(companyInfo);
        
        /* By default, this property contains a Null String ("") which means
           no header will be displayed within the printed report. The Report 
           Header data which merely consists of string text. The Page Header 
           (or headers for multiple pages) is never visible within the Text 
           Area of the report. Only when the report is printed with a paper 
           printer. */
        report.setReportHeader("Loan Payments Report");     // Report Header (Report Title)
        
        /* By default, this property contains a Null String ("") which means
           no footer will be displayed within the printed report. The Report 
           Footer data which will consist of the current page nunber being 
           printed and a Time-Stamp consisting of the current date and current 
           time of the printing.    
        
           The Page Footer(s) is never visible within the Text Area of the
           report. Only when the report is printed with a paper printer. */
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mma");
        String timeStamp = now.format(formatter); 
        report.setReportFooter("Page {0}  -  " + timeStamp); // {0} means current number of the page being printed.
     
        // Display the Report Window.
        report.show(); 
    }
}
```

**The InputFile class:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class InputFile {

    private Scanner reader;
    private String dataFilePath;
    
    public InputFile(String dataFilePath) {
        this.dataFilePath = dataFilePath;
        initReader();
        
    }
    
    private void initReader() {
        try {
            reader = new Scanner(new File(dataFilePath));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data File Not Found!", 
                        "File Not Found!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean eof() {
        if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            reader.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public String readString() {
        String line = reader.nextLine().trim();
        if (line.startsWith(";") || line.isEmpty()) {
            line = "";
        }
        return line;
    }
    
    public String readWord() {
        String word = reader.next().trim();
        if (word.startsWith(";") || word.isEmpty()) {
            word = "";
        }
        return word;
    }
    
    public int readInt() {
        int val = 0;
        try {
            val = reader.nextInt();
            return val;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    public long readLong() {
        long val = 0L;
        try {
            val = reader.nextLong();
            return val;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0L;
        }
    }

    public double readDouble() {
        double val = 0.0D;
        try {
            val = reader.nextDouble();
            return val;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0.0D;
        }
    }
    
    public float readFloat() {
        float val = 0.0f;
        try {
            val = reader.nextFloat();
            return val;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return 0.0f;
        }
    }
    
    public void close() {
        reader.close();
    }

    public String getDataFilePath() {
        return dataFilePath;
    }

    public void setDataFilePath(String dataFilePath) {
        this.dataFilePath = dataFilePath;
    }
}
```

If you create the `"fcrc loan data.txt"` file with the contents as shown above and save in your project directory (folder) then run this demo runnable application, you should see a GUI wondow that looks like this:

[image]

Use the Scroll-Bar to view the entire report or select the <kbd>Print</kbd> button to print the report. To close the GUI, slect the <kbd>Close</kbd> button.

Keep in mind, the Text Area of the form is not interactive. As a matter of fact, the Text Area is non-editable.

The **LoanPaymentsReport** class is within the next post:

Answer (score 0):

The **LoanPaymentsReport** Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.text.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.Size2DSyntax;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaPrintableArea;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.OrientationRequested;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class LoanPaymentsReport {

    private final String LS = System.lineSeparator();

    private JFrame jf;
    private JTextArea jta;
    private JScrollPane jsp;

    private String companyName = "", companyAddress = "", companyCity = "",
                   companyState = "", companyZip = "", companyCountry = "",
                   companyPhone = "", companyEMail = "";
    
    private String customerName = "", customerAddress = "", customerCity = "",
                   customerState = "", customerZip = "", customerCountry = "", 
                   customerPhone = "", customerEMail = "";

    private String dataFilePath = "";

    // Report Header Text (Null String ("") for no Header):
    private String reportHeader = "";
    // Report Footer. (Null String ("") for no Footer): 
    private String reportFooter = ""; //"Page {0}" for page number in footer. 

    private int month, day, year, loanPaymentCode;
    private double loanAmount, loanInterestRate;

    
    // Contructor #1:
    public LoanPaymentsReport() {
        initForm();
    }

    // Contructor #2:
    public LoanPaymentsReport(double loanAmount, double interestRate, int paymentCode, Integer... dateOptions) {
        int opMonth = LocalDate.now().getMonthValue();
        int opDay = 1;
        int opYear = LocalDate.now().getYear();
        if (dateOptions.length > 0) {
            if (dateOptions.length >= 1) {
                if (dateOptions[0] == null || dateOptions[0] < 1 || dateOptions[0] > 12) {
                    opMonth = LocalDate.now().getMonthValue();
                }
                else {
                    opMonth = dateOptions[0];
                }
                opDay = 1;
                opYear = LocalDate.now().getYear();
                if (dateOptions.length >= 2) {
                    if (dateOptions[1] == null || dateOptions[1] < 1 || dateOptions[1] > 31) {
                        opDay = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        opDay = dateOptions[1];
                    }
                    opYear = LocalDate.now().getYear();
                    if (dateOptions.length >= 3) {
                        if (dateOptions[2] == null || dateOptions[2] < 1800 || dateOptions[2] > 2500) {
                            opYear = LocalDate.now().getYear();
                        }
                        else {
                            opYear = dateOptions[2];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        this.loanAmount = loanAmount;
        this.loanInterestRate = interestRate;
        this.loanPaymentCode = paymentCode;
        this.month = opMonth;
        this.day = opDay;
        this.year = opYear;
        initForm();
    }
    
    // Contructor #3:
    public LoanPaymentsReport(String dataFilePath) {
        this.dataFilePath = dataFilePath;
        initForm();
    }

    
    private void initForm() {
        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Loan Payments Report");
        jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        jf.setSize(720, 550);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#F4F3F1"));

        jta = new JTextArea();
        jta.setEditable(false);
        jta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", jta.getFont().getStyle(), 12));
        // Set margins in TextArea
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white, 1);
        jta.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 10)));

        jsp = new JScrollPane(jta);
        jsp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 3));
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(680, 450));
        jf.add(jsp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(jf.getWidth(), 50));
        buttonPanel.setOpaque(true);
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#F4F3F1"));  // A very light gray

        // Form Buttons
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print");
        printButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            printReport();
        });
        buttonPanel.add(printButton);

        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(jta,
                    "<html>Are you <font color=red><b>sure</b></font> you want to close report?",
                    "Close Report?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (res == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                jf.dispose();
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(closeButton);

        jf.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void show() {
        readInFileData();
        displayCompanyTitle();
        displayCustomerInfo();
        displayAmountAndInterestRate();
        displayHeader();
        displayTable(loanAmount);

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            jf.setVisible(true);
            jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        });
    }

    private void readInFileData() {
        if (!dataFilePath.isEmpty()) {
            InputFile loanInfo = new InputFile(dataFilePath);
            while (!loanInfo.eof()) {
                this.customerName = loanInfo.readString();
                this.customerAddress = loanInfo.readString();
                this.customerCity = loanInfo.readString();
                this.customerState = loanInfo.readString();
                this.customerZip = loanInfo.readString();
                this.customerCountry = loanInfo.readString();
                this.customerPhone = loanInfo.readString();
                this.customerEMail = loanInfo.readString();
                this.month = loanInfo.readInt();
                this.day = loanInfo.readInt();
                this.year = loanInfo.readInt();
                this.loanAmount = loanInfo.readDouble();
                this.loanInterestRate = loanInfo.readDouble();
                this.loanPaymentCode = loanInfo.readInt();
            }
            loanInfo.close();
        }
    }

    private void displayCompanyTitle() {
        jta.append(LS + LS);
        if (!companyName.isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(companyName + LS);
        }
        if (!companyAddress.isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(companyAddress + LS);
        }

        String[] city_State_Zip = {companyCity, companyState, companyZip};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (String str : city_State_Zip) {
            if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(str);
            }
        }
        if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(sb.toString() + LS);
        }

        String[] country_Phone = {companyCountry, companyPhone};
        sb.setLength(0);
        for (String str : country_Phone) {
            if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(str);
            }
        }
        if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(sb.toString() + LS);
        }

        if (!companyEMail.isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(companyEMail + LS);
        }
    }

    private void displayCustomerInfo() {
        if (!customerName.isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(String.format("%-65s%-20s%n", " ", customerName));
        }
        if (!customerAddress.isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(String.format("%-65s%-20s%n", " ", customerAddress));
        }
        
        String[] city_State_Zip = {customerCity, customerState, customerZip};
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (String str : city_State_Zip) {
            if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(str);
            }
        }
        if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(String.format("%-65s%-20s%n", " ", sb.toString()));
        }
        
        String[] country_Phone = {customerCountry, customerPhone};
        sb.setLength(0);
        for (String str : country_Phone) {
            if (!str.isEmpty()) {
                if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(str);
            }
        }
        if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(String.format("%-65s%-20s%n", " ", sb.toString()));
        }
        
        if (!customerEMail.isEmpty()) {
            jta.append(String.format("%-65s%-20s%n", " ", customerEMail));
        }        
    }

    private void displayAmountAndInterestRate() {
        DecimalFormat numFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        NumberFormat currencyFormat;
        currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        jta.append(LS);
        //DecimalFormat amountFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
        jta.append(String.format("%-30s %12s%n", "LOAN AMOUNT:", currencyFormat.format(loanAmount)));
        //DecimalFormat rateFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
        jta.append(String.format("%-30s %12s %30s %2d %n%n", "INTEREST RATE:",
                numFormat.format(loanInterestRate) + "%", "PMT CODE:", loanPaymentCode));
    }

    private void displayHeader() {
        String header = String.format("%-10s %15s %15s %15s %15s %15s%n",
                "Payment #", "Due Date", "Payment", "Interest",
                "Principle", "Balance");
        String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));

        jta.append(underline + LS);
        jta.append(header);
        jta.append(underline + LS);
    }

    public void displayTable(double amount) {
        int paymentNumber;

        double payment = 0, interest, principal, balance;

        DecimalFormat numFormat;
        numFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        NumberFormat currencyFormat;
        currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        balance = amount;
        paymentNumber = 0;
        double totalPayment = 0;
        double totalIntPaid = 0;
        while (balance > 0.0d) {

            paymentNumber++;
            String dueDate = calcDueDate(month, day, year, paymentNumber);
            interest = calcInterest(balance, loanInterestRate);
            if (balance <= payment) {
                payment = balance;
                principal = balance;
                balance = 0;
            }
            else {
                payment = calcPayment(loanPaymentCode, amount);
                principal = calcPrincipal(payment, interest);
                balance = calcBalance(balance, principal);
            }
            totalPayment = totalPayment + payment;
            totalIntPaid = totalIntPaid + interest;
            String paymentString = String.format("%8d %19s %13s %15s %15s %15s%n",
                    paymentNumber, dueDate, "$" + numFormat.format(payment),
                    currencyFormat.format(interest), currencyFormat.format(principal),
                    (balance == 0d ? "(" + currencyFormat.format(balance) + ")" : 
                            currencyFormat.format(balance)));
            jta.append(paymentString);

        }

        jta.append(LS);
        jta.append(String.format("%17s %10s %13s %15s%n", " ", "Totals:",
                currencyFormat.format(totalPayment),
                currencyFormat.format(totalIntPaid)));
        jta.append(LS);

    }

    public static double calcPayment(int code, double amount) {
        double payment;
        payment = 0;

        switch (code) {
            case 0:
                payment = 50.00;
                break;
            case 1:
                payment = 55.00;
                break;
            case 2:
                payment = 75.00;
                break;
            case 3:
                payment = 100.00;
                break;
            case 4:
                payment = .05 * amount;
                break;
            case 5:
                payment = .06 * amount;
                break;
            case 6:
                payment = .05 * amount;
                break;
            case 7:
                payment = .04 * amount;
                break;
            case 8:
                payment = .03 * amount;
                break;
            case 9:
                payment = .02 * amount;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Bad payment code");
        }
        return payment;
    }

    public static double calcInterest(double balance, double rate) {
        double interest;
        interest = (((rate / 12d) * balance) / 100.0d);
        return interest;
    }

    public static double calcPrincipal(double payment, double interest) {
        double principal;
        principal = payment - interest;
        return principal;
    }

    public static double calcBalance(double balance, double principal) {
        balance -= principal;
        return balance;
    }

    public static String calcDueDate(int month, int day, int year, int payNum) {
        String monthStr = "";
        month = month + payNum - 1;
        year = year + (month / 12);
        month = month % 12;
        if (month == 0) {
            year--;
        }
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
                monthStr = "Jan";
                break;
            case 2:
                monthStr = "Feb";
                break;
            case 3:
                monthStr = "Mar";
                break;
            case 4:
                monthStr = "Apr";
                break;
            case 5:
                monthStr = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                monthStr = "Jun";
                break;
            case 7:
                monthStr = "Jul";
                break;
            case 8:
                monthStr = "Aug";
                break;
            case 9:
                monthStr = "Sep";
                break;
            case 10:
                monthStr = "Oct";
                break;
            case 11:
                monthStr = "Nov";
                break;
            case 0:
                monthStr = "Dec";
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid month: " + month);

        }
        return monthStr + " " + day + ", " + year;
    }

    private void printReport() {
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = null;
        MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat(reportHeader);
        MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat(reportFooter);
        jta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", jta.getFont().getStyle(), 10));
        jf.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        try {
            PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
            Paper paper = new Paper();
            double margin = 0;

            // Left, Top, Right, Bottom 
            paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, paper.getWidth() - 5.0d, paper.getHeight());
            pf.setPaper(paper);

            //pj.setPrintable(new MyPrintable(jta), pf);
            pj.setPrintable(jta.getPrintable(header, footer), pf);

            if (attr == null) {
                boolean portrait = true;
                Insets insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                float leftMargin = insets.left;
                float rightMargin = insets.right;
                float topMargin = insets.top;
                float bottomMargin = insets.bottom;
                if (portrait) {
                    attr.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
                }
                else {
                    attr.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
                    leftMargin = insets.top;
                    rightMargin = insets.bottom;
                    topMargin = insets.right;
                    bottomMargin = insets.left;
                }
                attr.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
                MediaSize mediaSize = MediaSize.NA.LETTER;
                float mediaWidth = mediaSize.getX(Size2DSyntax.MM);
                float mediaHeight = mediaSize.getY(Size2DSyntax.MM);
                attr.add(new MediaPrintableArea(
                        leftMargin, topMargin,
                        (mediaWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin),
                        (mediaHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin), Size2DSyntax.MM));
            }
            
            boolean printComplete = false;
            if (pj.printDialog()) {
                pj.print(attr);
                printComplete = true;
            }

            if (printComplete) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jta, "You can pick up your report from the printer!",
                        "Print Job Completered", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jta, "Print Job Canceled!",
                        "Print Canceled!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        catch (PrinterException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoanPaymentsReport.class.getName())
                                    .log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        jta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", jta.getFont().getStyle(), 12));
        jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    /* Inner class for a custom Printable for the JTextArea we will print.
       This class is used within the printReport() method only.       */
    class MyPrintable implements Printable {

        JTextArea str;

        MyPrintable(JTextArea getStr) {
            str = getStr;
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
            if (pageIndex != 0) {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            Rectangle componentBounds = str.getBounds(null);
            g2.translate(-componentBounds.x, -componentBounds.y);
            g2.scale(1, 1);
            boolean wasBuffered = str.isDoubleBuffered();
            str.paint(g2);
            str.setDoubleBuffered(wasBuffered);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }

    }

    
    // GETTERS & SETTERS
    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return jf;
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return jta;
    }

    public JScrollPane getScrollPane() {
        return jsp;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCompanyAddress() {
        return companyAddress;
    }

    public void setCompanyAddress(String companyAddress) {
        this.companyAddress = companyAddress;
    }

    public String getCompanyCity() {
        return companyCity;
    }

    public void setCompanyCity(String companyCity) {
        this.companyCity = companyCity;
    }

    public String getCompanyState() {
        return companyState;
    }

    public void setCompanyState(String companyState) {
        this.companyState = companyState;
    }

    public String getCompanyZip() {
        return companyZip;
    }

    public void setCompanyZip(String companyZip) {
        this.companyZip = companyZip;
    }

    public String getCompanyCountry() {
        return companyCountry;
    }

    public void setCompanyCountry(String companyCountry) {
        this.companyCountry = companyCountry;
    }

    public String getCompanyPhone() {
        return companyPhone;
    }

    public void setCompanyPhone(String companyPhone) {
        this.companyPhone = companyPhone;
    }

    public String getCompanyEMail() {
        return companyEMail;
    }

    public void setCompanyEMail(String companyEMail) {
        this.companyEMail = companyEMail;
    }

    public void setCompanyInfo(String[] companyInfo) {
        setCompanyName(companyInfo[0]);
        setCompanyAddress(companyInfo[1]);
        setCompanyCity(companyInfo[2]);
        setCompanyState(companyInfo[3]);
        setCompanyZip(companyInfo[4]);
        setCompanyCountry(companyInfo[5]);
        setCompanyPhone(companyInfo[6]);
        setCompanyEMail(companyInfo[7]);
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }

    public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
    }

    public String getCustomerCity() {
        return customerCity;
    }

    public void setCustomerCity(String customerCity) {
        this.customerCity = customerCity;
    }

    public String getCustomerState() {
        return customerState;
    }

    public void setCustomerState(String customerState) {
        this.customerState = customerState;
    }

    public String getCustomerZip() {
        return customerZip;
    }

    public void setCustomerZip(String customerZip) {
        this.customerZip = customerZip;
    }

    public String getCustomerCountry() {
        return customerCountry;
    }

    public void setCustomerCountry(String customerCountry) {
        this.customerCountry = customerCountry;
    }

    public String getCustomerPhone() {
        return customerPhone;
    }

    public void setCustomerPhone(String customerPhone) {
        this.customerPhone = customerPhone;
    }

    public String getCustomerEMail() {
        return customerEMail;
    }

    public void setCustomerEMail(String customerEMail) {
        this.customerEMail = customerEMail;
    }
    
    public String getDataFilePath() {
        return dataFilePath;
    }

    public void setDataFilePath(String dataFilePath) {
        this.dataFilePath = dataFilePath;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getLoanPaymentCode() {
        return loanPaymentCode;
    }

    public void setLoanPaymentCode(int loanPaymentCode) {
        this.loanPaymentCode = loanPaymentCode;
    }

    public double getLoanAmount() {
        return loanAmount;
    }

    public void setLoanAmount(double loanAmount) {
        this.loanAmount = loanAmount;
    }

    public double getLoanInterestRate() {
        return loanInterestRate;
    }

    public void setLoanInterestRate(double loanInterestRate) {
        this.loanInterestRate = loanInterestRate;
    }

    public String getReportHeader() {
        return reportHeader;
    }

    public void setReportHeader(String reportHeader) {
        this.reportHeader = reportHeader;
    }

    public String getReportFooter() {
        return reportFooter;
    }

    public void setReportFooter(String reportFooter) {
        this.reportFooter = reportFooter;
    }
}
```